# Workers who take time off during final month

Tags: resignation, sickness, leave-of-absence

As a manager in IT I've noticed in the past that employees who have decided to leave for another job might take more sick leave or make greater use of a company's remote working policy during their last month of employment.

It may be the idea that since they're leaving the company anyway in a short time, they're not likely to face much disciplinary action and the time period is short enough to not be able to measure productivity. They may think that sneaking in a bit of paid time off could also allow them time to set up interviews and so on.

So a question to managers: Do you show leniency since they'll soon be gone, or for the sake of the company and team keep tighter tabs on soon-to-be-leaving team members? How would you spot such behaviour and what measures might you take to curb it?

Comment: Q: do you mean the month AFTER they have resigned or their final month when they are looking at getting a new job but just INTEND to leave?  Just you mention interviews, which I'd assume they've already done (and have an offer) if they've already resigned?  So is Bob looking to leave, and taking some days off for interviews, of has he resigned and is just trying to get some paid time off before he goes (in which case you cut him loose early).

Comment: A good point, I meant the month after they have resigned. If the industry is quite hot, they might be confident to find a new job within the notice period. Or alternatively they may want to spend some free time prepping for the new role that they already were offered, or doing second and third interviews. I've edited my post slightly to make this clearer.

Comment: are you asking how to avoid paying people for accrued annual leave? payroll sorts that out not you

Comment: This question is almost 3 years old. But anyway, if they have already resigned, then 95 % of the time they have already signed the contract at the new company and are just doing the notice period, no? So any extra time off is not for interviewing. Note that in Europe, any leftover vacation days and/or flextime are often used to shorten the notice period. If not, then the old company will pay that in the final paycheck.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Do you show leniency since they'll soon be gone, or for the sake of
>   the company and team keep tighter tabs on soon-to-be-leaving team
>   members? How would you spot such behaviour and what measures might you
>   take to curb it?

(note: In my answer, I'm assuming that these individuals have already handed in their notice, and that you are seeing changed behavior afterward.)

I don't think it's a matter of leniency, just a matter of "what are you going to do - fire them?"

If your company has a written policy around sick time (such as requiring doctor's notes) or remote work, then certainly follow whatever the policy dictates.

And hopefully, when you received the resignation, you talked with the individuals one-on-one and spoke about leaving on a professional note.

Other than that, the only real possibility is to hint that you would withhold a good recommendation in the future. ("I'd like to be able to give you a great recommendation down the road, and write about how professionally you handled your last weeks with us.")

If you are still uncomfortable with this, talk to HR. This certainly isn't the first time this has happened in your company. HR could give you some additional (and possibly company-specific) guidance. They could also step in and talk with the offending individual(s).

Comment: Good answer. Just one thought to contribute... Being a new manager, I went to HR for advice on how to handle my first resignation letter. Their advice included making it clear that that their end date was a mutual agreement, and that misbehavior between now and then could cause us to release the person earlier, which would affect pay and medical benefits.

Comment: @KentAnderson what this answer is missing is what you communicate to the people you'll still be working with in a months time. Cajoling someone back to disinterested work is marginal against losses here. For example, How will your next person resign if you cut someone loose mid-notice? Incidently, HR are typically for bookkeeping and legal, rather than experts on people and teams.

Answer (score 8):

You can, of course, discuss options with HR. If the transition of the work is being handled well, I would tend to take a more lenient stance especially when there is a long notice period like this. The reason why is that your other employees will take note of how you behave. Giving people the benefit of the doubt in one situation makes people feel as if they will get that benefit in another.  If you are viewed as being a total jerk about such things, you may create a morale problem and a flurry of notice periods.

Further, do you really want someone who is unhappy and leaving to be there infecting your other subordinates with their unhappiness? I have worked with plenty of people who I wished would just go home during their notice period because their attitude was rubbing off on others. In one case we did actually send a guy who was retiring home just to keep him from bringing productivity down. So are you really losing much if they work from home or call in sick? Are they going to be productive if you force them to come in? If they aren't productive, will they harm other people's productivity by wanting to chat or a creating more discontent?

Further, people often don't get paid for unused sick leave when they leave but it is part of their overall compensation, can you really blame people for wanting to use it? If you crack down on these people, then they will just use it before giving notice, so did you gain anything?

You should not expect a lot of work from the person who has given notice other than doing transition tasks. They are gone mentally. That is why I am opposed to dragging out notice periods for such a long time. The sooner they go the better. There is no job that cannot be transitioned in a week that can be transitioned in a month. Jobs that require specialized people to take them over (and you only have the one position), are not benefited by the month because likely the replacement also had to give that notice and still is not there when the person leaves. If an employee died or got seriously ill, there would be no transition.

Now I probably would call them to task if they were not doing the transition work I needed done. However, at this point, what kind of stick do you really have? If you fire them you are getting no transition either. Your HR can tell you if this is even a viable option in your legal jurisdiction.  It is actually better to have things documented before people give notice, so that transition needed is minimal.

Comment: lol 1 month = long notice period.  Try the UK where 1 month is standard and 3 months is becoming more and more usual!

Comment: I know in other countries long periods happen, but I submit that they are useless. Dragging out a person leaving is in the worst interests of the company. You have an unhappy person who is not motivated to do as much as he used to and who will be talking to other people about how great his new opportunity is. Why would any sane person want that from subordinates? You won't have the replacement on board because he too will have this long notice period, so what did you gain from it? I just don't see any corporate gain whatsoever from a long notice period vice a short one.

Comment: _"They are gone mentally"_ that's it. Their heart is out, their mind is out. Let them go.

Comment: @HLGEM it also protects the employee and gives them a buffer in case of redundancy - and its also a powerful social marker only higher class professional workers have long notice periods.

Comment: @HLGEM In some fields/companies you don't need the month to *train* the new employee, you need it to *find* them. Having a month makes things more planable for both sides, sometimes at the cost of making things more tedious. But otherwise: +1 :-)

Comment: To elaborate on @AllTheKingsHorses' comment, "*jobs that require specialized people to take them over (and you only have the one position)*" almost certainly benefit from the person who is leaving the role participating in interviews.

Answer (score 3):

May I flip this slightly in reverse too and mention that your behaviour (you being the company as well as the manager) towards the leaving person has an effect

I've left a company recently whereby I handed my notice in, mutually agreed my leaving date with HR (4.5 weeks notice rather than 4 to help the company out) and looked forward to working as I usually did and contributing.

The next day I went to a meeting with my manager and several other senior people. As I walked in, my manager said to me "What are you doing here?" A little stunned I said "I'm invited to this meeting aren't I?". He said in front of everyone "I assumed now you are leaving you don't care anymore"

What do you think happened to my motivation right then? Perception is reality and I knew there are then, the narrative of my last few weeks had already been written regardless of what I did. Needless to say, and I'm not proud, downing tools was a phrase that could have been used to describe me. And after I left, apparently lots of problems were attributed to me and the "well, once he handed his notice in, he stopped fixing things and contributing", even problems that had been around months and months

Everyone always thinks this is one-way but it isn't.

Comment: 4.5 weeks rather than 4 — wow, what an effort :) but seriously speaking, people who stay find it easier to blame issues on the guy who just left. Unfair, but hey.

Comment: Exactly. Perception is reality.

Comment: While i'm not in the same boat, I hear you Mike. When someone here was redundant, the manager made a horrendous comment at our next meeting about how useless they were that I suppose was meant to be some form of joke. No one laughed, and I bit my tongue because I wouldn't have made a measured response... A bit of emotional maturity on the part of managers would go a long way, and i'd hazard a guess that the attitude shown to you by the manager played some role in you leaving anyway. In any case, such an approach instills the direct opposite of loyalty and doing the right thing by the company.

Answer (score 2):

Most employers I know don't allow the use of vacation during the two week notice period. Those 10 working days are to be used to training a replacement, but more likely to document their tasks, clean up what they can and then train a member of the staff.  But these companies also paid the departing employee for unused vacation or unused Paid time off (PTO) if it was combined with sick into one pool. The employee would rather preserve their vacation hours to make that departing check as big as possible.

In cases where they didn't get paid for unused vacation what was seen is telling the boss they were quitting right after returning from a few days off. They at least got a few days to run errands paid for by the boss. These days were between when they signed the offer letter and when they told the company they were leaving.

Unless you know they are looking there is no way to prevent the second situation.

In the first case negotiate the end date if they are taking a week off in the middle of the notice period. If they keep calling in "sick" during the notice period, and you are in an at-will state you could decide to terminate their employment early. But the risk is that they will leave the transition a mess.

Comment: In many companies it is the same pool of hours.

Comment: In most countries, not being paid accrued vacation time is unheard of and illegal. In the UK, the only exception is when you accept payment in lieu of notice, you will not accrue vacation time, and when you are sent on "gardening leave" (officially employed but not working during your notice period), your holidays will be scheduled in that time. My very first job for 3 months between school and university actually paid me six days of holiday plus 50% overtime, because I didn't take the holiday when I left.

Answer (score 1):

As you say: "What are you going to do? Fire them?"

If the company has a policy that says no sick time after turning in your resignation, then I think you could not pay them for such days. If you're big enough to have an HR department, they should know.

Beyond that, there's not a lot you can do. You might mention to the employee that they should be careful not to burn bridges. When you quit a job, you never know if somewhere down the road you might not want to come back, or if someone you worked with here shows up at another company that you work for later. I've had several times that I've worked with someone at company A, quit that job to go to company B, then some time later quit that job to go to company C, and found the person from company A was now working at C. Made me glad that I hadn't left screaming about how stupid this person was and how I was glad to be away from them, etc.

If the person doesn't have the integrity to live up to their commitment to give 2 weeks (or whatever the agreed time is) to assisting in a transition, you're probably better off without them in your company anyway. If you have to pay them for 2 weeks for nothing, that might just be how it is.

Comment: Obviously if the company doesn't allow sick time after I turn in my resignation, I will do my best to spread my flu infection to as many people as possible. And I will visit HR a few times with my flu.

Comment: While it's certainly possible that someone could just happen to get sick the day after turning in his resignation, I'd strongly suspect that the illness is fake. And no one is saying that they are going to force you to come to work at gunpoint, just that, if you don't come to work after turning in your resignation, you won't get paid.

Answer (score 1):

Based on whatever your expectations are, you have to determine if they're getting things done or not.

You catch more bears with honey. Work out a plan to either wrap up a project, do a brain dump, train a replacement or whatever. If they get that done, let them work from home or tell them you're more "open" to taking time off.

Don't just assume everyone will abuse the situation. Always let people know what is expected. If they're not relying on you for a future reference, that's a bit on you or maybe you should have let them go sooner.

Answer (score 0):

I personally couldn't care less about paid time off. If I'm playing sick during my final two weeks it's likely because I'm just completely fed up, and if I'm quitting it's certainly because I feel I don't help and aren't wanted at that place (otherwise I'd have stayed). In this situation, I feel no one loses if I play sick. Bosses and customers who hate me don't have to deal with me, and I don't have to deal with them, and I can prepare for my new job. If I thought I actually had something to contribute to this company I would not call in sick.

Answer (score 0):

In my own experience as an employee who's left an IT position after using PTO / vacation before doing so; I scheduled a full week of vacation, a month or so out.

A couple of weeks after taking my vacation, I gave notice. I'd even scheduled, prior to giving my notice, to use a floating holiday that then fell within the notice period.

None of it was intentional as some sort of "I'm going to use all of my time and leave"; I was burnt out and couldn't handle the job and needed the time off.

After coming back from the vacation, and getting back into the stressful job, I realized I just wanted to leave. I hadn't been interviewing before taking the PTO, or even during. I gave my notice, not having anything lined up, and started submitting applications in my free time during the notice period. I coincidentally got a very quick response, and the floating holiday I'd taken in the middle of my notice period ended up being a day that I flew out for an interview somewhere else.

If you're talking about someone who takes up their vacation time **before handing in their notice**, There's a chance they've just been unhappy for some time, which lead to the higher than usual vacation time usage.

At some point later on, they likely realized the time off wasn't helping, and they'd really only be satisfied if they left.